# How to run a component's method in angular from iframe as its container

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

here is angular code

**testing.component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {data} from '../../assets/data.js';
import { IPost } from '../_models/IPost.js';

import {WindowRefService} from '../WindowRef.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testing.component.css']
})
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  callInIframe() {
    console.log('Call In Iframe');
  }

}
```

In routine manner such code does not lunch in any container like **iframe**, however I want to lunch in iframe. Something like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
   <!--Angular app load in iframe , below code -->
    <iframe src="/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="900px"></iframe>
    <script>
        **I want to Call Angular method here**
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I Call **callInIframe()** in script tag of index.html. @gzoechi

Comment: Is there any specific reason for adding iframe at index.html ?? if not you can add iframe at the component HTML and then you can trigger the method in the component ts file while iframe gets loaded

Comment: angular app has to use some libs in level of iframe and that libs are not importable to angular app so I have to import app in iframe. @sunilbaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the iframe on the template of the **main component** instead of the index.html

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    this is an iframe for may website on an angular project
</p>
<iframe src="https://mansourcodes.com/"></iframe>
```

### See Example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqec9u?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: angular app has to use some libs in level of iframe and that libs are not importable to angular app so I have to import app in iframe @MansourAlnasser